# Accessing watershed boundary for lakes in R

Tags: r, polygon, watershed, lakes, nhd

I have had success accessing unique database IDs and polygons for various lakes in the US. I'm now looking to get polygons for the watersheds associated with these lakes, but have stumbled a bit.

Example- I get a lake polygon from a GPS point using the Hydrolinks package:

```
library(hydrolinks)

Lat<-37.70127
Lon<- -97.0508

Lake <-link_to_waterbodies(Lat, Lon, "Name", dataset = c("nhdh", "hydrolakes", "nhdplusv2"), buffer = 50)
```

The result is Santa Fe Lake in Kansas. (ID = 45827774)

Using the `nhdR` package, I can get the polygon associated with this lake

```
library(nhdR)
dt <- nhd_load(c("KS"), c("NHDWaterbody"))
Poly<-dt[dt$Permanent_Identifier == 45827774]
```

I'm using results from the streamstats API as my "true" watershed (see screen shot from streamstats API for this lake).

The reachcode for the "Poly" object is "11030017001699". And if I try to calculating watershed data from the first 10 digits of the reachcode, the basin doesn't match what I get from the streamstatas API.

[image]

I tried using the pour point for this lake (Hydrolakes lists this as -97.05319   37.709), but calculating a watershed based on these points only gets me a small section of the true watershed.

```
library(streamstats)

#Pour Points
PLon<- -97.05319
PLat<- 37.709
ws1 <- delineateWatershed(xlocation = PLon, ylocation = PLat, crs = 4326,
                      includeparameters = "true")
```

So I'm assuming that the accuracy of these pour points is not good enough to use streamstats to calculate entire lake watersheds.

Using tools from `nhdplusTools` package works for this lake

```
library(leaflet)
library(nhdplusToos)



 #Step 1
  point <- sf::st_sfc(sf::st_point(c(PLon, PLat)), crs = 4326)
  #Get nhdplus_id from point
  ID<-discover_nhdplus_id(point)
  
  #Get Basin 
  nldi <- list(featureSource = "comid", featureID = ID)
  basin <- get_nldi_basin(nldi_feature = nldi)
  
  
  leaflet() %>%
    addPolygons(data = basin) %>%
    addCircleMarkers(data = point,
                     #lat = ~lat, lng = ~long,
                     color = "red",
                     radius = 2) %>%
    addTiles() #Add tiles adds defualt map
```

Which seems to work well. But I don't always have pour points for lakes, or some of my pour points do not give me a full watershed. Using random GPS points from within a lake polygon gives me unreliable results.

```
 Lat1<- 37.72797
 Lon1<- -97.82922
 ID = 135039628
```

Plugging the above coordinates into the `get_nldi_basin` function only gets a small aspect of the entire watershed

And if I used these coords for a small pond:

```
Lat2<- 39.27623
Lon2<- -94.89211
ID = 159110681
```

I get a huge watershed

So using the `get_nldi_basin` seems to be limited to my ability to get an accurate pour point. I'd really prefer a method that gives me an accurate watershed boundary for an entire lake using the entire lake polygon, or a match to the permanent NHD ID.

Comment: I'm looking into it but hidrolinks is not available for R 3.6. Which one are you using ? I'm not sure about your final goal. Do you want to get a layer of watershed boundary (with ID) given a pair of coords ?

Comment: I'm using Hydrolinks ‘0.10.0’ running on R 3.6.1. Though you may be able to get the waterbody ID using nhdR with "ID <- nhd_query(Long, Lat, dsn = c("NHDWaterbody"))". I've been avoiding using nhdR, even though they have a function to find upstream networks ('extract_network') as I'm running on a Mac and nhdR requires the use of 7-zip to unpack NHD files

Comment: But to make thing easier- I will edit the above question add the ID from Hydrolinks

Comment: Which level of aggregation are you pulling watershed data for? The Missouri/Missisippi basin contains a whole series of nested watersheds.

Answer (score 1):

The following reference might help you:
https://vt-hydroinformatics.github.io/rgeowatersheds.html#the-watershed-delineation-toolprocess

Also, another possible idea:
Maybe failure can be caused by an imperfect DEM (like: are your lake really represented as "flat" in the DEM?)
In this case, maybe searching the watershed for each point where a tributary river enters the lake, plus that of the pour point, might help. You might also take a point every n meters on the lake borders (instead of the entry points of tributary river)

(this is an intuition I got seeing figure 2 of https://www.researchgate.net/publication/251003807_Modeling_dissolved_organic_carbon_mass_balances_for_lakes_of_the_Muskoka_River_Watershed/figures?lo=1 )

Answer (score 1):

I was a little bit confused trying to guess what is your goal, but I followed your last note "a method that gives me an accurate watershed boundary for an entire lake using the entire lake polygon".

I have to say that, using linux I found some issues trying to load the date from the `nhdr` package. So I will put all my code hoping it can help others with the same issues.

Here is the code that replicates your process but corrects things not working in linux (i guess...):

```
library(devtools)
library(hydrolinks)
devtools::install_github("markwh/streamstats")
library(streamstats)
library(nhdR)
library(rgdal)
library(curl)
library(httr)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(mapview)
library(sf)
library(rgeos)
library(leaflet)
library(nhdplusTools)
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Getting the nhd information from KS lakes (check README in github documentation)
KSID <- '11'
# get a vpu export
nhd_plus_get(vpu = KSID, "NHDSnapshot")
nhd_plus_get(vpu = KSID, "NHDPlusAttributes")
nhd_plus_get(vpu = KSID, "NHDPlusCatchment")

# get layer info and load layer
nhd_plus_list(vpu = KSID, "NHDSnapshot")
nhd_plus_info(vpu = KSID, "NHDSnapshot", "NHDWaterbody")

# dt <- nhd_plus_load(vpu = KSID, "NHDSnapshot", "NHDWaterbody") # sometimes doesn't work
# I had to do this in ubuntu 20.04 instead
# Load the shp in qgis --> export to .gpkg and then read...
dt <- st_read('/home/cesarkero/.local/share/nhdR/NHDPlus/MS_11_NHDSnapshot/NHDWaterbody02.gpkg')
mapview(dt)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# ¿Find Santa Fe lake?
reachcode <- "11030017001699"
poly <- dt %>% dplyr::filter(REACHCODE == reachcode)

#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Get Basin 1
x1<- -97.05319
y1<- 37.709
ws1 <- delineateWatershed(xlocation = x1, ylocation = y1, crs = 4326,
                          includeparameters = "true")

p1 <- sf::st_sfc(sf::st_point(c(x1, y1)), crs = 4326)
ID1 <- discover_nhdplus_id(p1)
ID1
nldi1 <- list(featureSource = "comid", featureID = ID1)
basin1 <- get_nldi_basin(nldi_feature = nldi1)

# Get Basin 2
x2<- -97.82922
y2<- 37.72797
ws2 <- delineateWatershed(xlocation = x2, ylocation = y2, crs = 4326,
                          includeparameters = "true")
p2 <- sf::st_sfc(sf::st_point(c(x2, y2)), crs = 4326)
ID2 <- discover_nhdplus_id(p2)
ID2
nldi2 <- list(featureSource = "comid", featureID = ID2)
basin2 <- get_nldi_basin(nldi_feature = nldi2)

# Get Basin 3
x3<- -94.89211
y3<- 39.27623
ws3 <- delineateWatershed(xlocation = x3, ylocation = y3, crs = 4326,
                          includeparameters = "true")
p3 <- sf::st_sfc(sf::st_point(c(x3, y3)), crs = 4326)
ID3 <- discover_nhdplus_id(p3)
ID3
nldi3 <- list(featureSource = "comid", featureID = ID3)
basin3 <- get_nldi_basin(nldi_feature = nldi3)

leaflet() %>%
    addPolygons(data = basin1, color = 'blue') %>%
    addPolygons(data = basin2, color = 'orange') %>%
    addPolygons(data = basin3, color = 'gray') %>%
    addCircleMarkers(data = p1,
                     #lat = ~lat, lng = ~long,
                     color = "green",
                     radius = 2) %>%
    addCircleMarkers(data = p2,
                     #lat = ~lat, lng = ~long,
                     color = "red",
                     radius = 2) %>%
    addCircleMarkers(data = p3,
                     #lat = ~lat, lng = ~long,
                     color = "black",
                     radius = 2) %>%
    addTiles() #Add tiles adds defualt map
```

These are the basins:
[image]

Now, using the full lakes layer from `ndhr` as the base cartography for lake,  you can capture the basin based using the centroid, instead of the ID (which I found issues working with). May be the ID is better but I don't know the data enough. So here is how you can get the basin for a lake.

```
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# select the little lakes
lakes <- dt %>% arrange(AREASQKM) %>% filter(row_number()== 1:3)
# center <- st_centroid(lakes) # ploblems with branched lakes
center <- st_point_on_surface(lakes)

x <- as.vector(st_coordinates(center)[,1])
y <- as.vector(st_coordinates(center)[,2])

ls <- list(); ws <- list(); ps <- list(); IDs <- list(); basins <- list()
for (i in seq_along(x)){
    # hydrolinks
    ls[[i]] <- link_to_waterbodies(y[i], x[i], "Name",
                              dataset = c("nhdh","hydrolakes","nhdplusv2"),
                              buffer = 50)
    # streamstats
    ws[[i]] <- delineateWatershed(xlocation = x[i], ylocation = y[i],
                                  crs = 4326, includeparameters = "true")
    
    ps[[i]] <- sf::st_sfc(sf::st_point(c(x[i], y[i])), crs = 4326)
    IDs[[i]] <- discover_nhdplus_id(ps[[i]])
    nldi <- list(featureSource = "comid", featureID = IDs[[i]])
    basins[[i]] <- get_nldi_basin(nldi_feature = nldi)
}

# merge layers
bs <- do.call(rbind, basins)
ps <- do.call(rbind, lapply(ps, function(x) st_as_sf(x)))

leaflet() %>%
    addPolygons(data = lakes, color = 'blue') %>%
    addPolygons(data = bs, color = 'red') %>%
    addCircleMarkers(data = ps,
                     #lat = ~lat, lng = ~long,
                     color = "green",
                     radius = 3) %>%
    addTiles() #Add tiles adds defualt map
```

[image]